# Iteration over variable names in python?

Tags: python, variables, names

I have a group of variables named k1, k2 k3....k52. They variables are lists/numpy arrays depending on the scenario. Essentially I'd like to perform the same manipulation on them en masse within a loop, but am having trouble ierating over them. Essentially what i'd like is something like this:

```
for i in arange(0,52):
  'k'+ str(i) = log10(eval('k' + str(i)))
```

Obviously i know the above wont work, but it gives the idea. My actual attempt is this:

```
for i in arange(0,10):

   rate = eval('k' + str(i))
   rate = np.array(rate,dtype=float)
   rate = log10(rate)
   rate.tolist()
   vars()[rate] = 'k' + str(i)
```

(Its changed to a numpy array so i can log it, and then back to a list so i change the variable name back to what it was) Thanks for any help you can provide. I get the feeling this is something quite simple, but its escaping me at the moment.

edit: thanks very much for the answers, i should have explained that I can't really store them a set array, they need to remain as independent variables for reasons i don't really want to go into.

Comment: Why not store them in a list or dict in the first place?

Comment: I wonder how many programming problems can be solved by adding or removing one layer of indirection.

Comment: This is a common question from people learning about Python data structures.  This approach is sort of like writing "Nathan's book #1", "Nathan's book #2", etc. on all your books, scattering them all over the house, and then trying to optimize a way to go through them.  If all you care about is that they're all in one place, put them in a bag (a `set`); if you care about the order too, put them in a pile (a `list`), and sort or not as you like; if you care about being able to access an individual one easily from its name, put them on the shelf (a `dict`).  No label-makers needed!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line:

```
vars()[rate] = 'k' + str(i)
```

has to be replaced by:

```
vars()['k' + str(i)]=rate
```

Comment: This won't work if it's in a function, and so isn't a very good idea.  The documentation explicitly says not to modify the result of `vars` (which is just the `locals()` dict.)`

Answer (score 6):

If the items are all globals you can use the `globals()` call to get a mapping, then manipulate them:

```
g = globals()

for i in arange(0,52):
    varname = 'k{}'.format(i)
    g[varname] = log10(g[varname])
```

but you *really* want to just store all those items in a list or dictionary instead.

Comment: Normally, I just right on using a `dict` for these problems, but since they're numbered sequentially, I might go with a list here... `k[1]`, `k[2]` ...  rather than `k1`,`k2` ... Of course, lists make even more sense if you index them from 0 rather than 1.  +1 for mentioning list here and making me check my gut reaction.